# SQL Server 2005 Difference in Values

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have this query:

```
SELECT ID, Value 
FROM Table 
WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Table WHERE RecID = 12637)

UNION

SELECT ID, Value 
FROM Table 
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table WHERE RecID = 12637)
```

I want this to dive me the difference between the two value results. But I also need it to only do so if the ID differ - which I believe won't be an issue since I believe only 1 result is returned if only one record.

**Update**

```
ID  |  Value
------------
100 | 23000
110 | 25000
```

The current query results are shown above. I'm looking for a way to get the result of 2000.

Story behind it I have a table that captures value for each entry. There could be 1 record or 15 which are subsequent revisions. I want to know the the difference between what was first reported in the first record `MIN(ID)` and the latest record `MAX(ID)`

Comment: So for each RecID, you want the first revision and the last revision? Well, knowing how to get the first and last, then you want to get the difference between them?

Comment: That is correct,  billinkc.

Thanks marc_s for cleaning up the format.  My first question still trying to figure out the proper way to use it.

Comment: What is the datatype of `ID` and `VALUE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ID` and `VALUE` are both `INT NOT NULL` then one way would be

```
SELECT RecID,
       CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(B), 6, 4) AS INT) - CAST(SUBSTRING(MIN(B), 6, 4) AS INT)
FROM   YourTable
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE
                             WHEN ID < 0 THEN 0x00
                             ELSE 0x01
                           END + CAST(ID AS BINARY(4)) + CAST(VALUE AS BINARY(4))) CA(B)
GROUP  BY RecID
```

Or alternatively another way (less cryptic and more robust to changing datatypes) is

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RecID ORDER BY ID ASC) RnAsc,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RecID ORDER BY ID DESC) RnDesc
FROM  YourTable      
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RnDesc = 1 THEN Value END) - MAX(CASE WHEN RnAsc = 1 THEN Value END)
FROM T 
WHERE 1 IN (RnAsc, RnDesc)
GROUP BY RecID
```

Or another way, courtesy of @Andriy that is more efficient than the `ROW__NUMBER` one as it avoids a sort operation is

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY RecID) MinId,
       MAX(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY RecID) MaxId
FROM  YourTable      
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Id = MaxId THEN Value END) - MAX(CASE WHEN Id = MinId THEN Value END)
FROM T 
GROUP BY RecID
```

Comment: @wildwally - Thanks. The "dirtier" first one could be more efficient though I'm not sure I would actually ever use it.

Comment: Something I have always had doubts about (and been unsure how to verify): if there was an index on `ID ASC`, would `ORDER BY ID DESC` benefit from it just as well as `ORDER BY ID ASC`? (Or does the question make sense to begin with?)

Comment: @AndriyM - Yes it would usually. SQL Server can scan indexes backwards and forwards. It can't currently do a backwards parallel scan though and also sometimes it doesn't consider backwards scans on composite indexes when it could do. e.g. IIRC an index on `RecID ASC, ID ASC` won't be used to avoid a sort for a `PARTITION BY RecID ORDER BY ID DESC`. Also if you have an index on `ID DESC` but are inserting monotonically increasing `ID` you could end up with a high degree of fragmentation.

Comment: I wonder then if replacing the row_numbers() here with min(id) over (partition) and max(id) over (partition) would be any better (changing, of course, the case expressions accordingly).

Comment: That's right. I am merely talking about changing the technique. Presently you are pulling e.g. the min value from the row where `RnAsc = 1`. After replacing that row_number with the window min() you would be pulling the min value from the row where `ID = MinID` (`MinID` being `min(ID) over (partition by RecID)`). Same for the max value. Essentially it would be the same, but you would avoid parallel scans in opposite directions, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @AndriyM - Yes the penny dropped. That does avoid a sort and shows up as a lower estimated cost.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more graceful way of doing this, but I think I have an approach. I find the first and last rows and the join the results together to make one row and then do the math. I wasn't 100% sure what you wanted in the case of there being only 1 row. I made it a left outer join to allow for something to exist in the mins and not the maxs and then as part of the join criteria, I exclude matching IDs. If that's not right, then nip off the `AND MN.ID <> MX.ID` line

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
,   RecID int NOT NULL
,   Value int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO
    #tmp
(
    RecID
,   Value
)
SELECT
    AC.object_id AS RecID
,   AC.precision + AC.scale AS Value
FROM
    sys.all_columns AS AC;


WITH MINS AS
(
    -- Find the first value for all the recids
    SELECT
        T.RecID
    ,   T.Value
    ,   T.ID
    FROM
        #tmp T
    WHERE
        T.ID = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(TI.ID) AS FirstID
            FROM #tmp TI
            WHERE TI.RecID = T.RecID
        )
)
, MAXS AS
(
    -- Find the last value for all the recids
    SELECT
        T.RecID
    ,   T.Value
    ,   T.ID
    FROM
        #tmp T
    WHERE
        T.ID = 
        (
            SELECT MAX(TI.ID) AS FirstID
            FROM #tmp TI
            WHERE TI.RecID = T.RecID
        )
)
SELECT 
    MN.RecID
,   MN.Value - COALESCE(MX.Value, 0) AS Delta
,   MN.ID AS FirstID
    -- might not exist
,   MX.ID AS LastID 
FROM
    MINS AS MN
    -- Assume we don't want things that were never updated
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        MAXS AS MX
        ON MN.RecID = MX.RecID
        AND MN.ID <> MX.ID
;
```

Comment: Thanks, with a few changes as you pointed out and additional conditions I got that to work.  Much Appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Your requirements are not quite clear to me, but you can do a set subtraction using EXCEPT

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer?  This seems more like a comment, then an actual answer.